# Determinant comparison about skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Suppose $S$ is a real skew-symmetric matrix, show that $\det(I+S) \geq 1$, where equality holds iff $S=0$.

My idea is to define a function $f(t)=\det(I+tS)$, for a fixed $S \neq 0$, and then show that $f$ assumes its minimum value only at $0$. It's easy to see that $f$ is a polynomial that only has even-power terms, but I can't see other properties that could lead to the conclusion.

Comment: I suppose that is meant to be a **real** skew symmetric matrix.

Comment: Yes, it's real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A skew-symmetric real matrix is diagonalizable over the complex numbers with purely imaginary eigenvalues $\pm i \lambda_1, \dots, \pm i \lambda_k$ (where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$). Here, the eigenvalues are listed according to their multiplicity. The eigenvalues of $I + S$ are $1 \pm i\lambda_j$ and so

$$ \det(I + S) = \prod_{j=1}^k (1 + i \lambda_j)(1 - i \lambda_j) = \prod_{j=1}^k (1 + \lambda_j^2) \geq 1.$$

If $\det(I + S) = 1$ then we must have $\lambda_j \equiv 0$ and so $S = 0$.